# Prove an action is transitive if one particular element holds that property.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble with the following problem:

Suppose $G$ acts on a set $A$, and suppose that there exists $a\in A$ with the property: for all $b\in A$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot a=b$. Prove that action of G is transitive.

I understand that the action is transitive for this particular element a, but I am having trouble with proving that it is transitive for any element.

Answer (score 1):

Since every element $b \in A$ lies in the orbit of $a$. Therefore $\text{Orb}(a)=A$. Recall that orbits form a partition of the set $A$. Thus in this case the partition has only one set in the family, which means there is only one orbit of this action, hence the action is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Given $b,c\in A$.  Take $g,h\in G $ with $ga=b$ and $ha=c$. So $(hg^{-1})b=ha=c$.